# umbraco: Contour package uploading error

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour

i am working on umbraco 6.1.6 project ,where to create a registration form i am using contour package,when i upload it , i got following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 
'Umbraco.Forms.Core, Version=1.1.0.25390, Culture=neutral, `PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`
```

To remove this error i tried to google.then i find that i have to add refrence in bin folder of umbraco.forms.core.dll .
so plz let me know  where can i find this dll (umbraco.forms.core.dll)

Answer (score 0):

Contour installs all required Dlls, Views, xslts etc. when you install the package. If you can not find it in your bin folder remove and reinstall it. By installing it you should have following Dll files in your bin folder:

Umbraco.Forms.CodeFirst.dll
Umbraco.Forms.Core.dll
Umbraco.Forms.Core.Providers.dll
Umbraco.Forms.References.dll
Umbraco.Forms.UI.dll

If you want to copy it manually, please download [this](http://our.umbraco.org/FileDownload?id=1095) and extract it and check Package.xml file. You can find the original file names for existing dll files in the extracted folder and find the one you need and rename it.

Comment: i have already try it ,but i didn't find any reference of  ajaxcontroltoolkit dll in package

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit.dll is not Contour's library. you can find it here http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx